# What is the formula for products in dihedral groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

Let $G \colon = \langle x, y \  | \  x^2 = y^n = e, \  x^iy^j = x^{i^{\prime}} y^{j^{\prime}} \ $ if and only if $ i = i^{\prime}, j = j^{\prime}, \  xy = y^{-1}x \rangle$.

That is, let $G$ be the set of all formal symbols $x^iy^j$, $i = 0, 1$, $\ j = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, where we assume that

$\ x^iy^j = x^{i^{\prime}} y^{j^{\prime}} \ $ if and only if $ i = i^{\prime}$, $\ j = j^{\prime}$;

$x^2 = y^n = e$, where $e$ is the identity element and $n >2$; and

$xy = y^{-1}x$.

Then how to express the product $(x^iy^j)(x^ky^l)$ as $\ x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$?

Comment: Hint: write it as $x^{i+k} x^{-k}y^{j}x^{k}y^{\ell}.$

Answer (score 0):

You get $yx=xy^{-1}$ from $xy=y^{-1}x$. You can prove, by induction, that $y^jx=x y^{-j}$.
Since $x^2=e$, you may assume that the exponent of $x$ is always $0$ or $1$.
This should be enough to express the product as you want.

The general idea (which doesn't work in general, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups)) is to try "to rearrange" the symbols which are not in the right order using the relations.